# Android WearableListenerService has to be called twice to receive Message

Tags: android, service, message, watch

I'm sending a Message from my Wear to the Service from my Handheld.
The first time I'm clicking a button on my handheld is just calling the onCreate method of the Service, the second time the service receives also the message. I can't figure out the problem.

Here is my Wear part:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        final PendingResult<NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult> nodes1 = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mApiClient);
        nodes1.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResult(NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult result)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < result.getNodes().size(); i++)
                {
                    Node node = result.getNodes().get(i);

                    PendingResult<MessageApi.SendMessageResult> messageResult = Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mApiClient, node.getId(), "/OPEN;"
                            + cnt, null);
                    messageResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<MessageApi.SendMessageResult>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(MessageApi.SendMessageResult sendMessageResult)
                        {
                            Status status = sendMessageResult.getStatus();
                            Log.d("", "##Status: " + status.toString());
                            if (status.getStatusCode() != WearableStatusCodes.SUCCESS)
                            {
                                //not getting there, always success
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I have following WearableListenerService:

```
public class DataLayerListenerService extends WearableListenerService implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener
{
    private GoogleApiClient mApiClient;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        Log.d("", "##DataService created");
        super.onCreate();
        if (null == mApiClient)
        {
            mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(Wearable.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }

        if (!mApiClient.isConnected())
        {
            mApiClient.connect();
            Log.d("", "##Api connecting");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        Log.d("", "##DataService destroyed");
        if (null != mApiClient)
        {
            if (mApiClient.isConnected())
            {
                mApiClient.disconnect();
            }
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent)
    {
        Log.d("", "##DataService received " + messageEvent.getPath());
        super.onMessageReceived(messageEvent);
        if (messageEvent.getPath().contains("/OPEN;"))
        {
            // only if called twice :(
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents)
    {
        Log.d("", "##DataService Data changed");
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0)
    {
    }
}
```

Maybe I also should mention that I ony have to click the button twice when the Service gets destroyed before, which happens some seconds after the click event.
So..in fact this is what happens:

> ### wear click
>
> ### service oncreate
>
> ### wear click
>
> ### service onMessageReceived
>
> ### wear click
>
> ### service onMessageReceived
>
> //wait some seconds
>
> ### service ondestroy
>
> ### wear click
>
> ### service oncreate
>
> ### wear click
>
> ### service onMessageReceived

Hope this is clear :-)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you tried the DataLayer SDK sample? The listenerService part doesnt extend ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener interfaces.Your connection callback methods might not be useful, because you can always check the connection by calling api client's isConnected() method. Only the wearable part extends these two interfaces. Also, Your onDestroy() method disconnect the api client, maybe thats why you need to click twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have solved it Phillip Adam - try commenting-out the line in your service in the onMessageReceived() method that makes the call to the superclass. That holds for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've been messing with this some more, and if you're still running into the bug of the listener service not firing on the first try, I've found that increasing the timeout interval helps. I had mine set to 10 milliseconds, but making it a larger value seems to have helped.

Check out the code in [WearableMainActivity.java in this gist](https://gist.github.com/jasonsalas/40137d7a6663da831431) I created for a project. Good luck! :)